# Symfony2/FOSUserBundle - Route issues with multiple bundles

Tags: php, symfony, user-management

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9826370/399584) problem, I need a separate login for both the admin and front end bundles of my site.  The admin is actually a separate bundle located in `vendors`.

Right now, my routing looks like:

app/config/routing.yml:

```
AcmeSiteBundle:
    resource: "@SiteBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

AcmeAdminBundle:
    resource: "@AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /admin/
```

Both of the bundles' individual routing.yml files have:

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_security_login:
    pattern:  /login
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }

fos_user_security_check:
    pattern:  /login_check
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }

fos_user_security_logout:
    pattern:  /logout
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:logout }
```

And my firewalls in security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        context: site
        pattern: ^/admin/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path:  /admin/login
            check_path:  /admin/login_check
        logout:
            path: /admin/logout
        anonymous:    true

    frontend:
        context: site
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
        logout:
            path: /logout
        anonymous: true
```

The problem is that the front end's automatically generated login links point to `/admin/login` rather than just `/login`, which is not what I want to have happen.

So, how can I make it use the `/admin/*` links when I'm there, but just the `/` links when I'm on the front end?  I need to keep their contexts linked as people logged into the admin side should stay logged in on the front end.

---

EDIT: I renamed my routes as the following:

SiteBundle's routing.yml (same as before):

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_security_login:
    pattern:  /login
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }

fos_user_security_check:
    pattern:  /login_check
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }

fos_user_security_logout:
    pattern:  /logout
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:logout }
```

AdminBundle's routing.yml:

```
_admin_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

_admin_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

_admin_user_security_login:
    pattern:  /login
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }

_admin_user_security_check:
    pattern:  /login_check
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }

_admin_user_security_logout:
    pattern:  /logout
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:logout }
```

`$ app/console router:debug` shows:

```
fos_user_registration_register         ANY    ANY    ANY  /register/
fos_user_registration_check_email      GET    ANY    ANY  /register/check-email
fos_user_registration_confirm          GET    ANY    ANY  /register/confirm/{token}
fos_user_registration_confirmed        GET    ANY    ANY  /register/confirmed
fos_user_security_login                ANY    ANY    ANY  /admin/login
fos_user_security_check                ANY    ANY    ANY  /admin/login_check
fos_user_security_logout               ANY    ANY    ANY  /admin/logout
fos_user_profile_show                  GET    ANY    ANY  /admin/profile/
fos_user_profile_edit                  ANY    ANY    ANY  /admin/profile/edit
_admin_user_security_login             ANY    ANY    ANY  /admin/login
_admin_user_security_check             ANY    ANY    ANY  /admin/login_check
_admin_user_security_logout            ANY    ANY    ANY  /admin/logout
```

As you can see, the only route that is correct is for user registration, and that's only because it's located *just* in SiteBundle's routing.yml.

Comment: I have a single bundle with a separate login for the backend. I have overwritten the loginAction of FOSUserBundle. This new action renders a new template for the admin login. My routes are "/admin/ login" for the backend and /login for the frontend. I can post the source code, if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out:

Since the FOSUserBundle was registered with my admin firewall in config.yml, it kept defaulting to its routes even after I renamed them.  So, turning them back to fos_*, and renaming the *site* bundle's routes seems to have fixed it.

Comment: so how does your config.yml file looks like (can you please post it as well)? what `firewall_name` did you used for `fos_user`?

Comment: ok i think i found it what i was looking for. basically it looks like that `fos_user. firewall_name` is used just to redirect users after successful registration if this is turned on in FOSUser. be sure to test this properly!