# redirect loop in symfony2, FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I developped my first site with symfony, so maybe I'm having a really obvious problem.

I had no problem on my local dev server, but since I send it to my live server and using app.php instead of app_dev.php, I am stuck in a redirect loop...

I looked over the internet and it seems that redirect loop are often caused by security.yml.

I'm using FOSUserBundle, maybe this is related ?!

**Edit :** Since everyone is pointing out the fact I'm using /admin as route for login may be one of the cause of my problem, I changed it to /admin/login but I still have the problem.

Maybe I should clarify some point. The website is in two part : 
- a frontend, which can be accessible for everyone
- a backoffice in which you can find some CMS like page and some other stuff..., only accessible by login.

On every page, even when I'm trying to access the homepage, I'm stuck in that loop. I end up with the requested url followed by a bunch of ///////////////////// at the end.

Anyway, here is my new security.yml :

```
security:
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    #in_memory:
    #    memory:
    #        users:
    #            user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
    #            admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_manager

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern: ^/admin/login$
        anonymous: true

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path: /admin/login
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /admin/menu
        logout:       ~
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

routing.yml :

```
mcr:
    resource: "@McrBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_security_login:
    pattern:   /admin/login
    defaults:  { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }

fos_user_security_check:
    pattern:   /admin/login_check
    defaults:  { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }
```

Any help will be greatly apreciated :)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you clear you cache by `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug` ?

Comment: I did. I tried with --no-warmup too.

Comment: What is your `check_path` in your `firewall > main` ?

Comment: Right now, none. I tried /login_check and /admin/login_check, but I was still stuck in the loop.

Comment: I guess it's because of `^/admin$` and the role assigned to `^/admin`. If you take a look at [http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form] section *Avoid Common Pitfalls* you will find the issue

Comment: I would also recommend to define real login path like `^/admin/login`

Comment: @Iknowkungfu FYI export code for live server is not necessary. You can use `app.php` in local env via sth like: `yourhostname.local/app.php/`.

Comment: @javad : Thanks I'll try that tomorrow, but i don't really understand what's wrong with my conf

Comment: @NHG : yes I know, but app.php is working smoothly on my dev environment. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Javad : I set a new path for the login, but I still have the loop. I added some details in my original post.

Comment: @Iknowkungfu check my below solution, I hope it fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

It likely has to do with how you have your routes setup;

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

When you try and access `/admin` internally symfony redirects this to `/admin/` and because your AC requires the role admin im guessing you are not logged in and want to be taken to your login page which im also guessing you have on `/admin`. Thus creating your non ending redirect loop.

I would recommend using `/admin/login` for your login route. You will need to update you routing.yml and security.yml

Comment: I just set another path, I still have the same problem. I edited the initial post.

Comment: @Iknowkungfu can you add your routing.yml as well

Comment: I added my routing.yml

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue. You need to define a separate firewall for the login path with anonymous access which is not shared with other firewalls:

```
firewalls:
   dev:
      pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false

   website:
      pattern: ^/
      security: false
      anonymous: true

   login:
      pattern: ^/admin/login$
      anonymous: true

   main:
      pattern: ^/admin
      form_login:
         provider: fos_userbundle
         csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
         login_path: /admin/login
         always_use_default_target_path: true
         default_target_path: /admin/menu
      logout:       ~
      anonymous:    true

access_control:
   - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
   - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
   - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately there is no change whatsoever :/ I really don't understand what's going on, sometimes, the website works for something like 5 minutes, then it goes down again. It makes no sense for me...

Comment: *the website works for something like 5 minutes*? What does it mean, do you mean you don't have the redirection issue for 5 mins then it redirect? This issue looks really weird

Comment: yes, exactly. It starts by adding only 2 or 3 slashes at the url (this loops redirect like 2 or 3 times) then no redirection at all for some time, and finally it goes down for long time.

Comment: Even weirder, when it works, I open another browser on the same PC and it doesn't necessary works. So I have one browser with the website working, and another with it stuck in a redirect loop at the same time.

Comment: Is the configuration you provided a full configuration you have in your `security.yml`?

Comment: the original post has the full file content (except the starting security: )

Comment: I edited the orignal post with the exact content of security.yml

Comment: Put `- { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }` in first line of your `access_control`

Comment: One more question: The `main:` firewall uses `fos_userbundle` and the pattern for that is `^/` Is it correct? I mean I thought you just want to use `fos_userbundle` for authenticating admin user I mean this pattern `^/admin/`, right?

Comment: - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } is already is the file.

Comment: _One more question: The main: firewall uses fos_userbundle and the pattern for that is ^/ Is it correct? I mean I thought you just want to use fos_userbundle for authenticating admin user I mean this pattern ^/admin/, right?_ Do you mean I should change the pattern from ^/ to ^/admin/ ? I think I already did this but had an error saying that I need a rule for ^/.

Comment: I still did not get my answer, do you want `fos_userbundle` be used just for admin? Otherwise I need to edit my answer

Comment: Sorry, yes, all pages under /admin/ must be authorized, everything else no login required.

Comment: `Invalid configuration for path "security.firewalls.main": The check_path "/login_check" for login method "form_login" is
  not matched by the firewall pattern "^/admin".` so I add the rule check_path: /admin/login_check but it give me a blank page and nothing in logs/prod.log

Comment: You don't need to add /login_check to `access_control` but need to define a check_path in `main` and **Be sure /login_check is behind a firewall** Check this documentation about Security in Symfony [http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form]

Comment: I did this : `check_path: /admin/login_check` under main: but I have this route configured `fos_user_security_check                ANY      ANY    ANY  /login_check`

Comment: I configured the route in routing.yml so it become /admin/login_check, I don't have the blank page anymore, but the redirect loop is back

Comment: Now I think it's not issue in `security.yml` there must be some issue in configuring FOSUserBundle routing. Check this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279378/symfony2-fosuserbundle-route-issues-with-multiple-bundles]

Comment: Furthermore, base on the FOSUserBundle documentation [https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-4-configure-your-applications-securityyml] I think there are conflicts between your routing and the default bundle routing and access control

Comment: Here is my FOSUserBundle routing : 
`fos_user_security_logout               ANY    ANY    ANY  /admin/logout`
`fos_user_security_login                ANY    ANY    ANY  /admin/login`
`fos_user_security_check                ANY    ANY    ANY  /admin/login_check`

Comment: I don't see where I may have conflicts.